# Unirest PHP: getting an error with a library file

Tags: php, unirest, mashape

I have downloaded unirest library from [here](https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-php) and extracted it to the folder with my site. I've put this piece of code on the page:

```
<?php 
         require_once "/unirest-php-master/src/Unirest.php";
         $response = Unirest\Request::post("https://api4yaware-yaware-data.p.mashape.com/account/json/v2/getEmployeeLastActivity?access_key=&email=demo%2Beco%40yaware.com",
  array(
    "X-Mashape-Key" => "TSJbkryFpxmshZKbe1UxI0T9L0ddp1UFplVjsnSXjugPiVmxPd",
    "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Accept" => "text/plain"
  )
);
echo $response;
         ?>
```

And I'm getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in
>   Y:\home\localhost\www\dashboard\unirest-php-master\src\Unirest\Request.php
>   on line 419

Screenshot:

[image: Error screenshot]

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Something is wrong on the library. Go to this file at this row and check for syntax errors. Or download a stable version of the lib.

Comment: You're running an obsolete version of PHP and can't use this library until you upgrade